# using the less command to read files contained in the my_school olleh folder

Tags: linux, command-line

> Use the less command to read the file contained in the my_school folder. Enter the content of the file here: *

```
root@ip-10-251-17-152:~# less my_school olleh
my_school is a directory
root@ip-10-251-17-152:~#
```

What could be the problem? am not getting to read the files contained within the folder.

Comment: If `olleh` is a file contained within `my_school`, then you may read it using `less my_school/olleh`

Comment: Your command tells `less` to show what's in `my_school` and `olleh`. The problem is that `my_school` is a directory, and `less` can't display the content of directories.